# Pentaho Data Integration - Dump Excel into table

Tags: excel, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I'm very new to this tool and I want to do a simple operation:

Dump data from an XML to tables.

I have an Excel file that has around 10-12 sheets, and almost every sheet coresponds to a table.

With the first Excel input operation there is no problem.

The only problem is that, I don't know why but, when I try to edit (show the list of sheets, or get the list of columns) a second Excel Input the software just hangs, and when it responds just opens a warning with an error.

This is an image of the actual diagram that I'm trying to use:

[image: Data Integration capture]

Comment: Try writing the Excel cells manually and run the job. what is the size of the excel file you are working with?

Comment: It's like 5MB file, some sheets have a thousands of rows

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical case of out of memory problem. PDI is not able to read the file and required more amount of memory to process the excel file. You need to give PDI more memory to work with your excel. Try increasing the memory of the Spoon. You can read [Increase Spoon memory](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/6.1/0H0/070/020/010).

Alternatively, try to replicate your excel file with few rows of data keeping the structure of the file as it is e.g. a test file. You can either use that test file to generate the necessary sheet names and columns in excel step. Once you are done, you can point the original file and execute the job.

Comment: Yes, @Rishu proposed the correct solution. For information, what takes a lot of memory is not to read the data, but to read the data structure with Apache POI. So, the suggestion is to read the structure on a small spreadsheet, and once done, use that structure (without re-decoding it) on the large xls.